# how to access a non getter/setter method of a java bean

Tags: java, jsf, javabeans, el

I have an xhtml page that gets values from a java bean:

```
<h:dataTable value="${myBean.getAccounts}" var="account">
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Account ID</f:facet>
            #{account.id}
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Account Name</f:facet>
            #{account.name}
        </h:column>

</h:dataTable>
```

The problem is that when I run this on a Tomcat 7 server, I get an error: getAccounts is not a myBean property. The java class's getAccounts method is a standalone method that returns some results.

Is there no way I can call this method?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The property name is *accounts*, not *getAccounts*. `getAccounts` is a getter that returns the property *accounts*

Answer (score 1):

EL treats any method with get/set prefix as a property, so if you call your method anything with that you can just omit the get/set part.

Answer (score 1):

Jeff's answer is correct. Just some additional info:

Your method is called getAccounts() but in EL you need to say #{mybean.accounts}

There is a good complete example of using a h:dataTable [here](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-datatable-example/)